# How to deal with unreferenced pages but exists in sitemap

Tags: seo, sitemap

Is it OK to have pages that are not referenced by any anchor links, but they do exist in the Sitemap file? Will Google penalise this behaviour or consider this as spam site?

Comment: This is precisely what a Sitemap is for. To allow Google to find hard to reach pages.

Answer (score 1):

That is fine. It is not always possible to link all of your pages. I have almost 600,000 pages not linked except with cross links between some of them. They are all in the sitemap. Google and Bing are fine with this. They have to be. They do not write the rules for the web.